# Is there any way to collect metric data of free kubernetes cluster in ibm cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I have created a free kubernetes cluster in ibm-cloud. I want to get the metric data like cpu utilization, memory utilization etc for that cluster. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service, monitoring is supported only for standard clusters. You can check out the monitoring options for standard clusters here - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_health.html#view_metrics

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there's enough capacity in a free cluster with it's 1 2x4 worker node, but you could try using a 3rd party integration like Kubernetes: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator